# Are comic superheroes considered sci-fi?

Tags: discussion, scope, comics

Would comic book superheroes (the non-magical ones, of course) be considered sci-fi?  I'm more of a Marvel fan, so I first think of Iron Man as a prime example in the "yes" camp, but I wonder what would others like Superman, Green Lantern, et cetera where their powers are not clearly rooted in technology and understood scientifically.

Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've always been a fan of superhero comics and I've always considered it a sub-genre of science fiction.  Some characters are certainly more "hard" sci-fi than others, of course.

Answer (score 13):

It depends on the comic, and what part of the work is being asked about.

Some superheroes, like Batman or Spider-Man, have mundane or fairly flimsy technobabble-based orgins ("I will train and dress up as a Bat", Peter Parker is bitten by a radioactive Stan Lee) and others like Green Lantern or the Fantastic Four, are clearly science-fiction (cosmic police, a flight into space to gain their powers). Also, pretty much all superheroes have been in some sort of cosmic event storyline at some point (The Infinity Gem saga, Crisis on Infinite Earths).

At the same time, there['s really not a clear dividing line. If a question asks, say, about Galactus's origin, sure, that's on-topic. Asking about how nobody recognizes Clark Kent to be Superman with a squint would be clearly off-topic. Superman's *origin* is clearly SF, but his work at the Daily Planet kinda isn't.

In summary, I suggest we **err on the side of being inclusive**, and in general **allow questions that ask about the science-fiction aspects of comic books**.

(If the comic book proposal becomes a site, we can migrate questions there at that time.)

Comment: Great answer, especially the point about not just the comic but about the question.

Comment: +1 for "radioactive Stan Lee", lol

Answer (score 5):

**Doctor Manhattan** from [Watchmen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchmen/) would be a good candidate.

> In contrast to other superheroes who
>   lacked scientific exploration of their
>   origins, Moore sought to delve into
>   nuclear physics and quantum physics in
>   constructing the character of Dr.
>   Manhattan. The writer believed that a
>   character living in a quantum universe
>   would not perceive time with a linear
>   perspective, which would influence the
>   character's perception of human
>   affairs.

Comment: Certainly would.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the comic.

Comment: Can you elaborate or give examples? What part of the comics would be on-topic and what parts would be off?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a clear distinction between sci-fi and fantasy. I think sci-fi *is* fantasy and the names are pretty much a matter of perspective or taste.

Just consider the words inverted and imagine a book of fiction about [real world, not fantasy land] science. Would that look like "science fiction"? No, it would be "popular science" or "history of science" (as Mortimer Adler notes, history is a sub-branch of fiction). At its most fantastic: really boring fiction.

Comic book super heroes could therefore fall into both camps, as indeed they do in these examples.

Comment: This question is basically out of date, since fantasy has been on-topic here for a long time.

Comment: OK. Does it hurt to add answers?

Comment: Not really…it’s just that the purpose this question was created for is sort of obsolete. It doesn’t matter (for the purpose of declaring what is on-topic, anyway) whether a work is science fiction or fantasy. But your answer is good nonetheless.

Comment: I don't understand why you say it's obsolete. Also, what do you think the question's purpose was all about? Curious about the direction you'd go further with this...

Answer (score 0):

There's a comic proposal in Area 51 right now. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3972/comic-books

Comment: This proposal has now been deleted.